# What was the Terumas Halishka used for? Where did the machatzis hashekel go?

Tags: mitzvah, beis-hamikdash, hekdesh

Firstly, what was the terumas halishka? Secondly, was it used for the machatzis hashekel? If yes, was it possible to donate to the terumas halishka without giving to it the machatzis hashekel?

If it wasn't used for the machatzis hashekel then where did the machatzis hashekel go after it was donated?

Comment: It's the other way around - the machatzis hashekels ended up in the lishkah, and from it the terumas halishkah was taken. See Shekalim ch. 3, and Rambam, Hil. Shekalim 2:4ff.

Answer (score 2):

The Terumas Halishka essentially functioned as the centralised treasury of the Temple. The treasury was comprised of money set aside in a special ceremony from the half-shekels of every adult male Jew and was collected annually.

The Rambam tells us in [Mishnah Torah, Shekalim 2:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sheqel_Dues.2.4?vhe=Torat_Emet_363&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> When the shekalim were collected from each and every city, they were sent to the Temple with emissaries. They might be exchanged for golden dinarim, so that [they would not become a] burden on the journey. [All the funds] were amassed in the Temple.
>
> They were placed in one of the chambers of the Temple. All the doors to the chamber were closed [under lock and] key, and then they were covered with seals. All the shekalim that were collected there [were stored] in three large baskets. Each of the baskets was large enough to contain nine seah. The remainder [of the money] was left in the chamber.
>
> **The money in the baskets was referred to as terumat halishcah ("[the funds of] the chamber that were set aside"). [The funds that] remained besides [the funds] stored in the baskets were referred to as sheyarei halishcah ("the remainder within the chamber")**.
> ([Touger Translation](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/946890/jewish/Shekalim-Chapter-Two.htm))

The [Midrash Tanchumah, Ki Sisa 1](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Ki_Tisa.1.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) adds:

> When thou takest the sum of the children of Israel (Exod. 30:12). May our masters teach us: How many times each year did the Israelites bring their offerings to the Temple? Thus did our masters teach us: They brought them three times a year; on the first day of the months of Nisan, Iyar, and Elul. **On the first day of the months of Nisan and Iyar the offerings for the Temple treasury would be collected and the priests would approach the altar to seek forgiveness for the sins of Israel with the shekels they had contributed.** But why did they do so three times a year? In order that all the Israelites might be involved, throughout the year, in giving their contributions. Why did they begin to accumulate their contributions on the first day of Adar,2 though they did not bring it in until the first day of Nisan? It was done that way so that the offering would not become an unbearable hardship for the Israelites. Hence they (the priests) would remind the Israelites on the first day of the month of Adar (to prepare their offerings). (Sefaria translation)

This Temple fund would then serve the communal needs and requirements of the public. Rambam adds in [Shekalim 4:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sheqel_Dues.4.1?vhe=Torat_Emet_363&lang=bi):

> What [are the funds in] terumat halishcah used for? From [these funds] they would purchase the daily offerings sacrificed every day, the additional offerings [sacrificed on Sabbaths, Rashei Chodashim and festivals], all other communal sacrifices, and the wine libations [that accompany them].
>
> Similarly, [these funds were used to purchase] the salt that was placed on all the sacrifices,2 and similarly, the wood for the altar, if no wood was provided3 and it was necessary that it be purchased.
>
> [They were used to pay for spices contained in] the incense offering and the wages of those who prepared it,4 the showbread and the wages of those who prepared it, the omer [of barley], the two loaves, a red heifer, the goat sent to Azazel and the scarlet thread tied between its horns.
> ([Touger Translation](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/946893/jewish/Shekalim-Chapter-Four.htm))